# Why is the db.Model put method succeeding, but returning None?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create an entity of one kind, and then store it's `db.Key` in an existing entity of another kind's `db.ReferenceProperty`.

```
class A(db.Model):
    #...

class B(db.Model):
    refA = db.ReferenceProperty(A)
    #...
```

And in a handler for a page at `/test`:

```
b = existingEntityB
b.refA = A(
    #...
).put()
b.put()
```

According to [the docs, `put` returns the key, or raises an exception if it fails](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_put), so I believe this should store a reference to `A` in `b.refA`.

However, `None` is stored instead. Note that the `TransactionFailedError` exception is *not* raised, and the new entity of `A` *is* stored.

I have ruled out that `b` fails to be `put` back by `logging` the result of storing `A` - it returns `None` there.

Comment: Down voter, care to explain?

Comment: couldn't you use an ancestor query and a parent-child relationship instead?  If you don't have to worry about freezing entity groups, this might end up easier than what you're trying to do

Comment: That relationship wouldn't really make any sense for these models. What I'm trying [shouldn't be] difficult, as far as I can tell from the docs the above should work - and it should *never* return `None`.

Comment: I totally agree with you that it should never happen that way, I was just trying to figure out a quick and dirty workaround.

Comment: @Julldar Thanks, I appreciate it :) I ended up just storing and then querying for it, which is obviously not desirable, but it at least works.

Comment: I have encountered this again with a different model that does not have this relationship. Must be a(n annoying) bug. Works fine on production server.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the issue and I couldn't. In my application the code you provided correctly saves A's reference on my B entity. Could this be already solved (provided that it was broken at any time)?

Comment: It's still broken (and the source of much grief) for me.

Comment: Could you put the whole code? I have tried different ways and it always works for me.